# Adding VSTS package source to NuGet Package Explorer

Tags: nuget-package, nuget-package-explorer

I've moved my package repository to VSTS and tend to build packages using NuGet Package Explorer. A lot of my packages have inter-dependencies to others that I've created. My question is how to do I add my package feed into NuGet Package Explorer?

When I browser to it, I get a 401 Unauthorised.

[image: Trying to add package source]

I can get around this by manually editing the metadata, but want to make it easier on myself.

The actual feed has already added Visual Studio, and I can push (via the command line) and pull packages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VSTS uses an authentication scheme that is not (yet) supported by NuGet Package Explorer. There's a ticket on GitHub regarding the issue: https://github.com/NuGetPackageExplorer/NuGetPackageExplorer/issues/122

The current workaround is indeed doing it using the command line.